# Этимология слова "гончар"

Tags: этимология

Мне кажется, или слово "гончар" тюркского происхождения, поэтому и не имеет общего корня со словами "лепка", "глина" и т. д.?

Answer (score 6):

Нет, исконно русское, только сильно видоизмененное. Упрощение древнего "гърньчаръ" (ст.-слав. гръньчарь) - родственного "горн", "горнец" ("горшок").

гонча́р укр. гонча́р, др.-русск. гърньчаръ(Житие Нифонта 1219г.), горъчарь (Пандекты 1296 г.; см. Соболевский, Лекции 112), ст.-слав. гръньчарь (Супр.). От др.-русск. гърньць, ст.-слав. гръньць " горшок"; см. Бернекер 1, 371; Преобр. 1, 144 и сл.; Мейе, Et. 211.
(Фасмер).