# Пунктуация: запятые, двоеточие

Tags: пунктуация

Прочитал [вопрос](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/13293/%D0%AD%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%80) Fuchoin Kazuki и возник в свою очередь у меня вопрос, правильно ли стоит запятая после "кажется":

> Мне кажется, или слово "гончар" тюркского происхождения, поэтому и не имеет общего корня со словами "лепка", "глина" и т. д.?

Не смейтесь, пожалуйста, но пока я писал этот вопрос, у меня возник ещё один вопрос: и тоже о запятой...))) в моих же словах. Ой, ещё один!..))

Первый: не нужна ли запятая *перед "и возник"* в начале, а второй: верно ли двоеточие *после слова "вопрос".*

*Моё мнение о запятых:*

1. У Fuchoin Kazuki, по-моему, всё правильно (но я не совсем уверен), потому что запятая будет нужна, если вставить опущенное (например: "Мне только кажется так, или..."). Кстати, как я уже читал, запятая в этом случае спорная, так что я предположил, что она нужна лишь по мнению сторонников её постановки в подобных полных случаях.
2. Что касается запятой в моих словах, то мне кажется, что она не нужна. Опущено "я" ("я прочитал"), и можно подумать, что это ССП, если бы не то, что "я + глагол" и "у меня + глагол" близки по смыслу и не воспринимаются как два разных подлежащих, а скорее как одно. То есть "прочитал" и "возник" воспринимаются почти как  однородные члены, поэтому запятую ставить не хочется.

Верно я рассуждаю? Если нет, **то что неверно** и как правильно? Спасибо за ответы и простите за такой необычный вопрос (точнее нагромождение вопросов)!

Comment: Вы хоть бы ссылку дали на тот вопрос...

*Мне кажется или слово "гончар" тюркского происхождения?*

Абсолютно то же, что в классическом примере: *Ты понял меня или ударить тебя?* Запятая в вопросительном ССП не нужна.

Comment: Я просто не видел особого смысла указывать на сам вопрос. *Запятая в вопросительном ССП не нужна.* Повторяю, это спорный вопрос: http://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/423401/%D0%9E-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4-%D0%98%D0%9B%D0%98/423403#423403 — вот, например.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой Смысла "указывать на сам вопрос" нет никакого, согласна. Нет ни прямой, ни даже кривой аналогии. Но это становится понятно, **только когда тот вопрос прочтешь**. Другими словами, коли уж вы упомянули о нем, даже чисто ассоциативно,то источник должен быть указан, или (на худой конец) процитирован полностью. Потому, что иначе может возникнуть непонимание у неподготовленного читателя, вот как сейчас у  Niemand'а,

Comment: Хорошо, сейчас сделаю ссылку.

Comment: Это Niemand неподготовленный читатель? Сударыня @IrinaGL, у вас лишняя  запятая в последней фразе. Хо-хо?

Comment: @Niemand  1. Да. 2. Нет.

Comment: Аж два раза. http://search2.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%EF%EE%F2%EE%EC%F3%20%F7%F2%EE&p=14&docid=107842 Не надо так формально подходить к правилам, гражданин.

Answer (score 1):

```
Мне кажется, или слово "гончар" тюркского происхождения, поэтому 
и не имеет общего корня со словами "лепка", "глина" и т. д.?
```

По правилам запятой нет, причины объяснены: общая вопросительная интонация. Запятую автор поставила, видимо, не задумываясь, потому что предложение состоит из 3 частей, 2 и 3 соединены бессоюзно. Однако посмотрим на структуру: [Мне кажется] или ([слово "гончар" тюркского происхождения],
[поэтому и не имеет общего корня со словами "лепка", "глина" и т. д.])?

Вопросительная интонация  у всего предложения. Две большие структурные единицы - простое и бессоюзное сложное предложения - соединены **сочинительным**  союзом ИЛИ и **интонацией**. Запятой нет.

*Прочитал вопрос Fuchoin Kazuki, и возник в свою очередь у меня вопрос...* - запятая разделяет простые предложения в сложносочинённом, общего ничего нет, ставим запятую.

```
  ...возник в свою очередь у меня вопрос, правильно ли стоит 
  запятая после "кажется".                                              -
```

В данном виде сложноподчинённое предложение с придаточным, ЛИ играет роль союза, ставим запятую, но если бы в конце стоял вопросительный знак, возможно было бы двоеточие:

*...возник в свою очередь у меня вопрос: правильно ли стоит запятая после "кажется"?*

Двоеточие предупреждает, что дальше идёт вопрос, бессоюзное сложное предложение, второе раскрывает смысл первого.

Comment: Спасибо, Людмила, Вы всё очень доходчиво объяснили, хотя что-то я и так понимал, но не до конца, а теперь Вы всё разложили по полочкам. Один только вопрос остался, правда, правильно ли двоеточие здесь: *Не смейтесь, пожалуйста, но пока я писал этот вопрос, у меня возник ещё один вопрос: и тоже о запятой... (после слов "один вопрос")* Видимо, я плохо объяснил в самом вопросе.

Comment: Ирина пишет, что двоеточие может соединять только два полноправных простых предложения, но я недавно подумал: как же тогда перечисление, перед которым его тоже ставят? Если это только перечисление и всё, то это не полноценное предложение. Значит, всё-таки не обязательно вторая часть д. б. целым предложением?

Comment: Артем, еще в 1956 году для двоеточия обозначены три главных темы (тогда грамматический материал разбирался для каждого знака в отдельности): обобщающее слово перед перечислением, бессоюзное сложное предложение и предложения с пярмой речью

Answer (score 0):

> У Fuchoin Kazuki, по-моему, всё правильно (но я не совсем уверен),
>   потому что запятая будет нужна, если вставить опущенное (например:
>   "Мне только кажется так, или..."). Кстати, как я уже читал, запятая в
>   этом случае спорная, так что я предположил, что она нужна лишь по
>   мнению сторонников её постановки в подобных полных случаях.

Просто потому, что "или" соединяет два независимых предложения и не под какие оговорки на случай отсутствия  запятой не подпадает. 
Насчет запятой в вопросительном предложении. Мне кажется, тут неприменимо. Обычно запятая не ставится при наличии союза **при двух однотипных вопросах**, выражающих **очевидную альтернативу**. То есть когда обе части по смыслу являются составляющими одного вопроса - и грамматически допускают один **общий** ответ.

> Что касается запятой в моих словах, то мне кажется, что она не нужна.
>   Опущено "я" ("я прочитал"), и можно подумать, что это ССП, если бы не
>   то, что "я + глагол" и "у меня + глагол" близки по смыслу и не
>   воспринимаются как два разных подлежащих, а скорее как одно. То есть
>   "прочитал" и "возник" воспринимаются почти как однородные члены,
>   поэтому запятую ставить не хочется.

Думаю, что нужна и тут. А на основании чего вы делаете своё предположение? Тот же случай, ССП, ни под какие изъятия из общего правила не подпадающее.
Их там не так много, по сути актуально только одно - о наличии общих слов. Здесь я таких слов не вижу.

Это ССП, ваших рассуждений про глагол и ещё что-то там про "не воспринимается", я не понимаю в принципе. Грамматически это два разных предложения, с двумя разными основами. Более того - разного типа. А раз так, то либо ССП, либо СПП, но последнее требует другого союза. То есть даже не вдумываясь в смысл, можно сделать вывод о структуре предложения.
Может, конечно, я чего-то тут не вижу...

> а второй: верно ли двоеточие после слова "вопрос".

Я бы здесь оставила запятую или, если нужно подчеркнуть период, - тире.
Но формально и для двоеточия может найтись основание (раскрытие смысла предыдущего), хотя такая трактовка будет очень необычной. 
Впрочем, я тут сама себе не слишком доверяю, двоеточия - не мой "профиль" )))), я стараюсь избегать подобной нетрадиционной пунктуации, если нет твёрдой уверенности, зачем мне это надо. 
Подождите, найдутся грамотеи, ответят точно.

Хотя погодите, для двоеточия нужно иметь два очевидных предложения, да еще не соединенных союзом. Ну союз - ладно, И здесь если и союз, то не самостоятельный. А вот насчет того, что "и тоже о запятой" можно рассматривать как самостоятельное предложение... Это вряд ли. Получается, что не получается ))).

Comment: Спасибо, Ирина! А двоеточие верно поставлено?

Comment: Добавила про двоеточие.

Comment: Спасибо! Подожду ещё, может, Сибилла тоже скажет что-то. А Вы уверены, что в обеих частях д. б. именно самостоятельные предложения?

Comment: Да, это $161 а) и б)  Правил-56.  Других формулировок, принципиально отличных, я не помню. http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/rules/157-dvoe . А Сибилла, может, и скажет. Я бы скорее положилась на Людмилу, Виктора, там, с номером, Алекс_андра... Но не смею настаивать.

Comment: Действительно, Ирина, спасибо за ссылку!